# Wifi always breaks after using Windows

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, manjaro

When using only Manjaro, my desktop PC works just fine. But whenever I boot to Windows 10, after restarting my PC and switching back to Manjaro, my wifi connection does not work. I only get this:

[image]

This happens every single time I boot to Windows and then to Manjaro. Back when I didn't use Manjaro but Kubuntu, the problem also occurred but I'm not sure whether it occurred 100% reliably.

The only way of getting connectivity back that I have found thus far is just to reboot Manjaro (or Kubuntu). I don't actually need to log in for this. Rebooting on the login screen also resolves the problem.

My motherboard: MSI B450 Gaming Pro Carbon AC

How can I resolve this problem entirely or circumvent it quicker than always booting Manjaro twice after having used Windows?

---

Edit: I discovered that wifi doesn't break if I restart my PC and switch to Windows as attested above. In fact, it never seems to break if I do that. It's just that until today, I never pressed restart under Windows and then booted to Manjaro. If I shut my PC down under Windows and then start it up again booting to Manjaro, wifi breaks. But if I choose "restart" and boot Manjaro, wifi works perfectly fine.

Answering the question from the comments: The output I usually get from `rfkill` is:

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth hci0     blocked unblocked
```

This also is what it outputs after *restarting* from Windows to Manjaro. But after shutting my PC down under Windows and then booting Manjaro, it doesn't print the wifi entry and assigns ID 0 to bluetooth:

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE    SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   blocked unblocked
```

Comment: I'm wondering...  what does `rfkill` give you when it happens ?

Comment: @funilrys Thank you for your question. I edited my post.

Comment: That's strange... What does `journalctl -p 3 -xb` or `dmesg` says ? `-p 3` means error only and `-x` gives us more information and `-b` stands for "since last boot".

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem as you. And I noticed that my motherboard has the same integrated **Intel AC antenna (9260)** as you. I rebooted many times, going back and forth from dualboot Windows to Manjaro. I was also turning everything off and booting, but WiFi was still not appearing on Manjaro, but working perfectly in Windows.

I tried looking at **journalctl**, as [funilrys](https://superuser.com/questions/1554871/wifi-always-breaks-after-using-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment2377682_1554871) suggested. I found out that something was wrong with the phy0 interface that relates to WiFi part of the antenna, that could not be assigned because of some `**phy0: rt2x00usb_vendor_request: Error - Vendor Request failed**...`. The Bluetooth interface, hci0, on the other hand, was working fine.

On my dualboot Windows, I normally connect to PS4 controller using the integrated bluetooth, and the same goes with bluetooth speakers. I noticed that somehow, the bluetooth settings on Windows was connected to my PS4 controller, even though it was turned off and I hadn't used it in a day. **I manually disabled bluetooth on Windows' Action Center and tried rebooting into Manjaro again. And that was it. WiFi was finely working again.**

It looks like Windows blocks the interface if something goes strange with the bluetooth interface, so **I suggest you turn off/disable bluetooth on Windows before using Manjaro**, making sure this "blocking state" doesn't occur. This error had never happened to me before, and I usually switch over these two OSes...